# Reproject shapefile between two user projections

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, ogr2ogr, proj

I need to tranform a set of geometries that have been drawn in the wrong projection system in an other projection system. I tried to do this using this command :

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs bad.prj -t_srs good.prj input.shp output.shp
```

But I get identical geometries.

How I can do this ?

*bad.prj :*

```
+proj=lcc +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=44 +lat_2=49 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000
+a=6378137.000000000 +rf=298.257223563 +towgs=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m
```

*good.prj :*

```
+proj=lcc +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=44 +lat_2=49 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 
+a=6378137.000000000 +rf=298.257222101000 
+towgs84=0.055780000,0.053280000,-0.094620000,-0.002575800,-0.015582000,0.025185600,0.003308000 
+units=m
```

Comment: You may try to change the assigned projection instead of trying to reproject e.g `ogr2ogr -a_srs good.prj output.shp input.shp`. Your projection is the same, only the transformation is different but I could be wrong as I'm not a geodesy specialist and I can't confirm side effect with real data (yours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection is made from an ellipsoid. Both projections are made from the same ellipsoid and with the same projection, so there is not change in the geometries if you project from one to the other.

The difference is if you reproject output.shp or input.shp to other projection made from other ellipsoid (or base geographic reference). Because both definitions have a different relation to the WGS84 datum.

For example:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 reprojected_input.shp input.shp
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 reprojected_output.shp output.shp
```

In that case, *reprojected_input.shp* geometries will be different to *reprojected_output.shp* geometries.

Comment: when I go through a temporary layer in 4326 I see a change in geometry, and it corresponds to what I expect. However, there is one point I don't understand, the two projections don't have exactly the same ellipsoid (the decimals of the ```+rf``` parameter change a little), so why is can't reproject the geometry when I run my first command?

Comment: Some change must be in the decimals of Y coordinate of the geometries, due to the inverse flattening decimal change. You will see it in large geometries.